# Viviani's Window Problem: Seeking a Purely Geometric Proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Viviani's curve cuts out a portion of the surface of a sphere, in such a way that the remaining surface can be squared -- i.e. constructed with a straight edge and compass. My question is - is there a way to prove this result purely geometrically, without the introduction of calculus? I'm curious if the ancient greeks could have proved such a result themselves.

Comment: this question is *not a calculus question, nor is the "parametric" tag appropriate.